# How to test grpc API when proto file import other protobuf files

Tags: testing, grpc

I want to call grpc API with GUI tool. My test proto files import gogoproto/gogo.proto file, when I import my test proto file to Kreya, it returns error that gogoproto/gogo.proto was not found. How can I import my proto file to Kreya? Andis there any other tools can be used to test grpc API which proto files import other protobuf files?

Comment: `bloomrpc`, `grpccurl`.

Comment: Could you share your importer settings (proto files, import paths) and your proto directory / file structure?
Kreya also supports file descriptor sets. You could probably try to import precompiled file descriptor sets (see https://kreya.app/docs/importers/#import-via-file-descriptor-sets, https://docs.buf.build/reference/images#creating-filedescriptorsets-with-protoc)